# how to ssh virtualbox guest with host in bridged adsl connection

Tags: ssh, virtualbox, adsl

I have an ADSL bridged internet connection. My virtualbox host is windows 7 and guest is archlinux. 
(a) my guest ip is 192.168.1.x subnet 24

(b) Internet is available to both guest and host if host network is in NAT mode. but no ssh to host from guest because of NAT (in Nat guest IP is 10.0.2.x

(c) In host bridged network ssh is possible but no internet connection for guest

(d) If i switch to PPoE mode the problem will be solved. but I wish to remain in bridged adsl mode.

Is it possible to have internet connection to both machines and ssh to guest from host at same time in bridged adsl mode. There is only one physical network card

Comment: There is a simple work-around add another Network interface card as bridged or generic and assign the IP in same range as your PC's NiC is

Answer (score 1):

In host bridget network, when you have the ssh worknig, you should be able to make an internet connection for guest. For this you should use a firewall or proxy on host and configure the proper routing (or proxy) on guest.